# Cannot add record in new line in text file

Tags: python

I am trying to let the user add records to a text file that I have created. The record already has a few records added to it.

```
def add_new_employee():  
    with open("records.txt", "a") as storing_records: 
        storing_records.write(input("\n" + "please enter your details in the following format followed by commas between each field: User ID, Name, Age, Position, Salary, Years employed: "))
```

The problem is when I add a record for the first time it will work perfectly, the created record will be on a new line, but if I rerun the code and add in a new record then it will just join onto the end of the previous record and it will ignore the `\n`.

Comment: You are not actually writing a newline anywhere. The one you see is part of the prompt.

Comment: How would I go about adding the record to a newline then?

Comment: You need to add a newline character to the end of each like you write. Like input(...)+"\n"

Comment: Do you mean like this?

storing_records.write(input("please enter your details in the following format followed by commas between each field: User ID, Name, Age, Position, Salary, Years employed: ") + "\n")

It still won't work unless I am doing it wrong

Comment: That appears to be correct to me. What text editor are you using to open the file? Are you running Windows?

Comment: I got it to work by the solution below, but I am on windows and I am using pycharm

Comment: The code you have in your comment probably should work, although sometimes programming typos are difficult to spot. In either case the idea is right, you can append the "\n" to the return value of input(). Using a second variable is really a much better programming practice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you would create a variable first and .write the input in a separate line?
I also added the line break after the input. It worked for me once like that.

```
def add_new_employee():  
       with open("records.txt", "a") as storing_records:
           user_input = input("Please enter your details....")
           storing_records.write(user_input + "\n")
```

Comment: That got the records to start on a new line but when I am asking the user to enter their details it says "please enter your details in the following format followed by commas between each field: User ID, Name, Age, Position, Salary, Years employed: 
None"

For someone reason the word none appears

Comment: My apologies, please remove the print()-function. I mistakingly thought it belongs there, but it does not :D I tried the code now myself and it was working.